# Smallest Common Multiple of a range of numbers - works on Codepen.io and not on freecodecamp.org

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making the Freecodecamp certifications, and there's one problem I cannot see a solution to: the task is to calculate the Least Common Multiple (LCM) for an array of integers (that also means a RANGE of integers, between a min and a max value).

**The snippet below gives the correct answer here on SO, on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/mukagergely/pen/QeyvXg), on my local environment. But not on freecodecamp.org.**

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // sorting and cloning the array
  const fullArr = createArray(arr.sort((a, b) => a - b))
  // calculating the theoretical limit of the size of the LCM
  const limit = fullArr.reduce((a, c) => a * c, 1)
  // setting the number to start the iteration with
  let i = fullArr[0]

  // iteration to get the LCM
  for (i; i <= limit; i++) {
    // if every number in the fullArr divide
    // the number being tested (i), then it's the LCM
    if (fullArr.every(e => !(i % e))) {
      // stop the for loop
      break
    }
  }
  // return LCM
  return i;
}

// utility function to create the fullArr const in the
// main function
function createArray([a, b]) {
  const r = []
  for (let i = b; i >= a; i--) {
    r.push(i)
  }
  return r
}

// displaying the results
console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18]));
```

**The error what I see:**

- the code works correctly with 4 other arrays on freecodecamp.org
- the code gives false results - or no results at all for the array `[23, 18]`. If I get a result, it's not consistent (like 1,000,000 once, then 3,654,236 - I made these numbers up, but the behavior is like that). **The result of the `[23, 18]` input should be 6,056,820** (and it's that here on SO, but not on freecodecamp.org)

As this code is far from optimal I have a feeling that the code execution just runs out of resources at one point, but I get no error for that.

I read the **hints** on the page (yes, I tried the solutions, and they do work), but I'd like to submit my own code: I know my algorithm is (theoretically) good (although not optimal), but I'd like to make it work in practice too.

I also see that this question had caused problems to others (it's been asked on SO), but I don't feel it's a duplicate.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you are reading the question as meaning `the LCM of a range of integers between the two inputted numbers`, please do not use the word array. An array has a very specific meaning in javascript.

Comment: @Shilly - thx, but the input is an ARRAY of integers. And I also describe that the code (algorithm) works correctly on multiple sandbox platforms and with multiple input arrays. Except for the one I describe. I would like to get ideas as why it doesn't work on **ONE SPECIFIC SANDBOX** platform

Comment: Without extra context, I think most people will assume that `the array of integers` is the input to the function and will just use that array. Nothing in your question hints at that you need to calculate the range of those two numbers and calculate the LCM of that.

Comment: @Shilly Except that the snippet contains that function (and it is commented as such) and that **I also say that the snippet works correctly on SO**. But anyways - I cleared this possible ambiguity up by adding it to the first paragraph.

Comment: If you change it so that `smallestCommons` contains only `return 6056820`, then does it work? If so, then I'm thinking you might just need to make a more efficient solution.

Comment: You are sure that you can use ES6 syntax on freecodecamp? I would assume you can, but the solutions to this exercise that I looked at, are not using consts, destructuring and arrow functions. That would explain why it works almost everywhere, but not there.

Comment: @Shilly yes, I'm sure - it works with [1, 5], [5, 1], [1, 13], [2, 10], etc. - the code gives correc results. (And freecodecamp.org has a ES6 section too :) )

Comment: Good luck finding your demon. ;)

Comment: I tested it with much less number of iterations (modified the code `let i = Math.max(fullArr[0], 6050000)`) and it worked with [23, 18] on freecodecamp.org. Unfortunately this means I have to come up with another solution.

Comment: Thank you though for the thoughts. I might put the correct answer here when I have the new algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out it was a resource problem - the algorithm in my question was correct theoretically but wasn't optimal or effective.

Here's one that is more efficient in solving this problem:

```js
// main function
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  const fullArr = createArray(arr.sort((a, b) => a - b))
  return findLcm(fullArr, fullArr.length);
}

// creating the range of numbers based on a min and a max value
function createArray([a, b]) {
  const r = []
  for (let i = b; i >= a; i--) {
    r.push(i)
  }
  return r
}

// smallest common multiple of n numbers
function findLcm(arr, n) {
  let ans = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    ans = (((arr[i] * ans)) /
      (gcd(arr[i], ans)));
  }
  return ans;
}

// greatest common divisor
function gcd(a, b) {
  if (b == 0) return a;
  return gcd(b, a % b);
}


console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5]));
console.log(smallestCommons([5, 1]));
console.log(smallestCommons([2, 10]));
console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18]));
```

This method was OK on the testing sandbox environment.